# Dynamic Sized 2d char array in C?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc

How do I make `char files[256][256]` of dynamic size?
I have tried certain things but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.

Comment: You want this array in function or in main program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int size = 256;
    char (*da)[size][size] = malloc(sizeof *da);
    char (*da2)[size] = malloc(size * sizeof(*da2));
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `da` and `da2`?

Comment: @yentup it is pointer. It corresponds to `char files[256][256]`.

Comment: Oh, are those just two ways of doing it?

Comment: @yentup  yes, it is. other way `char *array = malloc(size*size);` It is necessary to process the index yourself.